# How to copy an application folder (.app) using terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, file-transfer

I have an application I downloaded in a form of `.app` file in downloads.
How can I copy it to `/Applications` using the terminal?

Since it is actually a folder I can use `cp` directly so it seems.
Using recursive operation requires creating the folder in `/Applications` prior to copying.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Technically speaking, you can just copy the folder, but there's more to an App than just the folder in `/Applications`; there are likely folders in `/Library` and `~/Library/`.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @Allan, Just "install" it.

Comment: Copy the file to Applications.  Once and done.

Comment: @Allan If there's no `Installer` package, and the normal way to install the application is just by dragging it to Applications, then nothing needs to be done in those folders.

Comment: @Barmar, I want the equivalent of dragging in finder to be done in terminal.

Comment: @Allan, I want to do the copying in the terminal.

Comment: See the answer by @nohilside below.  You're over-complicating this.  Is there a reason this needs to be done via Terminal?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin Understood, and that was my point. If all you need to do in Finder is drag to Applications, those other folders are irrelevant. Just use `mv` or `cp -r`.

Comment: Assuming that SRC and DEST are existing directories, `cp -R SRC/ DEST` copies the content inside SRC (with all subdirs etc.) into DEST. `cp -R SRC DEST` creates a directory `DEST/SRC` and copies everything from within SRC into this new directory. Note that the use of `SRC/` is specific to MacOS (i.e. BSD unix). If you are using Gnu _cp_, you have to write `cp -r SRC/* DEST`.

Comment: @user1934428, Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Done. Honestly, I feared that as an answer it would not be interesting enough, but if you feel so, here it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that SRC and DEST are existing directories, cp -R SRC/ DEST copies the content inside SRC (with all subdirs etc.) into DEST. cp -R SRC DEST creates a directory DEST/SRC and copies everything from within SRC into this new directory. Note that the use of SRC/ is specific to MacOS (i.e. BSD unix).

If you are using Gnu `cp`, you have to write

```
setopt -s dotglob
cp -r SRC/* DEST
```

The *dotglob* ensures that youa re also copying hidden files.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you don't need the application in `~/Downloads` afterwards, so

```bash
mv ~/Downloads/NAME.app /Applications/
```

should do. If you get a "Permission denied" error, add `sudo` in front and enter your password on the prompt.

Comment: What if only copy is needed?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin `cp -Rp` should also work. Please clarify your question though: the text asks for "copy", one comment for "the equivalent of dragging in finder".